# trying to update parent from child emit in vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a child component which emits an event in the created function

```
created: function(){
    this.$emit('onPageTitleChange', this.pageTitle);

    this.updateList()
}
```

i have this inside the #app div (that I'm assinging the vue instance to):

```
<h2 class="no-margin-bottom" v-on:onPageTitleChange="updatePageTitle">{{ pageTitle }}</h2>
```

and the vue app (the parent) has the upatePageTitle defined as:

```
methods: {
    updatePageTitle(title){
        this.pageTitle = title;
    }
},
```

The page title is not changing - what am I missing?

Comment: The listener has to be on the component that emits the event. The listener above is on an `h2` element.

Comment: I thought the parent (in this case the vue app) could listen for all events?

Comment: See this example. The parent *is* listening; but it has to listen in the right place. You can't just randomly place the listener. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BmygBx?editors=1010

Comment: ok, I understand that, but my content is being loaded by the router, and so I tried adding the event listener to `router-view` to no joy

Comment: You may be running into an issue with kebab-case vs camel-case. Look at the example now.

Comment: That's it, but grrr! I see an event of `onPageChange` and using the listener of `on-page-change` doesn't work either! I've seen many issues about using kebab case in place of camelCase as attributes are case insensitive (duh on me!).

Comment: you need to call the listener on child component not on <h2> tag

Comment: @user3791372 Yep, its covered in multiple places. If you define your template *in DOM* then you need to be wary of case issues. If you use string templates or single file components, you do not need to worry about case.

Comment: ahh, i haven't migrated to single file components yet! I'm just experimenting with vue in one file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were two issues here. First, the listener needs to be defined in the parent on the component that is emitting the event. Given a router is being used (as pointed out in comments) the listener can be added to the `router-view`.

```
<router-view @on-page-title-change="updatePageTitle"></router-view>
```

Second, when a template is defined *in DOM*, meaning, not a string or single file component template, then you need to be aware of camelCase vs kebab-case issues. [Attributes in HTML are case-insensitive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case). I find it best simply to avoid ever emitting camelCased events. That being the case, emit a kebab-cased event.

```
this.$emit('on-page-title-change', this.pageTitle);
```

And listen to it as shown above.

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

const Foo = { 
  template: '<div>foo</div>',
  created() {
    this.$emit("on-page-title-change", "This is the Foo title")
  }
}
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})



new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  data:{
    pageTitle: "This is the original title"
  },
  methods: {
    updatePageTitle(title){
      this.pageTitle = title;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.1/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>{{pageTitle}}</h2>
  <router-view @on-page-title-change="updatePageTitle"></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg.. it was the camel case that was not working. Thanks so much.